# htaccess 301 redirect to new page is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat

I have made 60 301 redirect form my old url to a new url. The syntax I made on each page is like this:

```
Redirect 301 "http://www.olddomain.com/product/foo" "https://newdomain.com/product/bar"
```

When I go to the old page `"http://www.olddomain.com/product/foo"` I am redirected to the new page, but not the URL I have defined: `"https://newdomain.com/product/bar"`. I am redirected to `"https://newdomain/product/foo"`.

So the redirect to the domain is correct, but the sub pages on the URL is the old one, instead of the new one.

Does anybody have an idea why that is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match domain name in `Redirect` directive.

I suggest using a `mod_rewrite` rule and that should be **placed before all other rules**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product/foo/?$ https://newdomain.com/product/bar [L,NC,R=301]
```

Make sure this is topmost rule and you test this in a completely new browser to avoid getting old cache.